# Представление кода в виде синтаксического дерева

Tags: парсер, c++

Необходимо по исходному коду построить синтаксическое дерево. Может быть, уже есть готовые библиотеки или программы? Если нет, то как проще это сделать?

Мои идеи: провести лексический анализ, получив на выходе токены, а затем применить синтаксический анализ для построения самого дерева. С синтаксическим вроде всё понятно, а вот с лексическим основная проблема - это составить грамматику для языка C++.

Comment: Немного дополнил ответ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не до конца ясна конечная цель, если это просто прокачать скилы, то стоит посмотреть в сторону другого языка, например чистого C, если же задача более реальная, то парсить C++ руками не стоит, ибо сложно и долго, я бы советовал воспользоваться готовым решением - [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org).

Clang предоставляет библиотеку [libclang](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html), при помощи которой можно получить AST для C/C++/ObjC/ObjC++.

У [Mike Ash](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/) есть неплохая [вводная в libclang](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2014-01-24-introduction-to-libclang.html). Кроме того можно посмотреть на [вот этот](https://github.com/AlexDenisov/bm_lint) мини-проект.

По двум предыдущим ссылкам информация об ObjC, но для вас не составит большого труда адаптировать это для С++.

**P.S.** парсить C++ при помощи Bison не получится, потому как грамматика у C++ не [контекстно-свободная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Контекстно-свободная_грамматика), придется писать парсер руками. Есть очень интересный рассказ на эту тему - [Редкая профессия](http://www.litmir.me/bd/?b=109763)

**UPD**

Кстати, если вам просто посмотреть дерево, то clang умеет это "из коробки"

```
clang -cc1 -fsyntax-only -ast-dump main.cpp
```

Comment: Спасибо, у меня как раз были сомнения насчёт Flex, думаю, с Clang проблем не будет

Answer (score 0):

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison -- генератор парсеров.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flex_%28%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%29  -- лексер.

Этого должно тебе хватить с лихвой.

И да, сейчас такие вещи ну очень редко пишут руками.

Comment: Грамматика C++ не context-free, его не получится парсить при помощи бизона, так что с головой этого не хватит :)

Comment: @AlexDenisov таблица символов. :)